# Aggregation Query Assistance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I'm having difficulty putting a complex(to me) aggregation query together for my data. Basically, here's the run down so everyone understands my conundrum.

I have two collections in this equation. "**training_documents**" and "**users**". Each user object has a key identified by name "**trainings**" which is an array of objects. Each object within this trainings array, contains 4 key/value pairs. An example of each object is below.

```
{
    "document": ObjectId('5a0350ad7df0977d94cffab6'),
    "trainee": ObjectId('59e51a4b7df0977d94cff95d'),
    "trainer": ObjectId('595fcc2e04cf707693257890'),
    "completion_time": "2018-04-23T21:28:22.747Z"
}
```

The users `trainings` array will contain many objects following the aforementioned format.

An example user data structure is below for reference.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5ad782283c55b056bcc39e3z",
        "site": {
            "site_id": "site1",
            "site_name": "Site One"
        },
        "user_name": "jsmith",
        "first_name": "John",
        "middle_name": "A",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "full_name": "John Smith",
        "title": "Duh Boss...",
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "last_login": "2018-04-27T14:27:27.014Z",
        "type": "full-time",
        "active": true,
        "__v": 0,
        "badge_id": "000001780343232123",
        "trainings": [
            {
                "document": ObjectId('5ae33622a766885a121b7362'),
                "trainee": ObjectId('5ad782283c55b056bcc39e30'),
                "trainer": ObjectId('595fcc2e04cf707693257890'),
                "completion_time": "2018-04-23T17:40:41.198Z"
            },
            {
                "document": ObjectId('5a0350ad7df0977d94cffab6'),
                "trainee": ObjectId('59e51a4b7df0977d94cff95d'),
                "trainer": ObjectId('595fcc2e04cf707693257890'),
                "completion_time": "2018-04-23T21:28:22.747Z"
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

I need to iterate through each object in the users `trainings` array during an aggregation. Basically, I need to `$lookup` the data using the key _id's "**document**" "**trainee**" & "**trainer**" from `training_documents`, `users`, & `users` respectively while keeping them each in their own objects/structure.

I've already tried to put a query together but haven't been able to figure out the iteration piece.

```
UserLdap.aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'training_documents',           // Search training documents collection...
        localField: 'trainings.document',     // Search query is the object id of trainings array.
        foreignField: '_id',                  // key to compare against is _id of trainings[].document.
        as: 'trainings.document'              // Return results in the trainings array on user.
        },
    },
]).exec((err, results) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json(results);
        console.log(results);
    }
})
```

Can someone please guide me on putting this query together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,

Apparently this isn't an easy thing or maybe I set it up weird. Albeit probably the best method, I opted out of the aggregation methodology. I just couldn't figure out how to implement some kind of `forEach` logic for each objectId in the trainings array.

Instead, when an admin clicks on the user profile training details, a GET is performed. The steps of what I do instead of aggregate is below.

1. The user object id is sent to a server route first.
2. Using user `objectId`, I `findOne` in my db collection.
3. Once found, I setup a new empty array and start a forEach on the user trainings array.
4. Within `forEach`, I setup a new empty object.
5. I setup two promises with `findOne` logic in each. One for the document `objectId` and one for trainer `ObjectId`. If I get data back, I resolve with the data received for each.
6. I execute the promises and using `.then()`, I take the data and then setup object properties of empty object I created earlier.
7. Once all needed properties are fulfilled, I then push the new object to the new empty Array I created earlier.
8. After all of this is complete, I send back status of 200 and newly created array to client. There, I can finally view the users completed trainings and export if necessary.

This issue took me far too long to work-around, but then again, I am still a newbie when it comes to coding.